# getElementsByTagName('a') not working

Tags: javascript

I am having this `a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');` and `a` seems like it is undefined. Because this

```
for (i=0; i< a.length; i++) {

        a[i].style.backgroundColor = bgColors;
        a[i].style.borderColor = borderColors[i];

            a[i].onmouseover = function () {
            a[i].style.backgroundColor = bgHoverColors[i];
            a[i].style.color = fontHoverColors[i];
            a[i].style.borderColor = borderHoverColors[i];

        };
    };
```

is printing `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`. I have looked a little but i didnt find something helpfull. I readed already the [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)
but i couldnt still fix my code.

Comment: Can you show us please how you tried to fix your code? Did you understand why the code you had posted didn't work?

Comment: The thing was the getElementsByTagName not my loop. Thanks Nico